# Adding an active class according to URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php/mysql driven menu. I am trying to add an active class to the menu item whenever the URI reflects that menu item (basically, when I am on that page) but every example I find is with a menu that is not populated through an array or repeater like mine.

How can manipulate the active class you see below so that it shows only when I am on that page?

Here is my menu

```
<?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($row['id'] == 2){ 
                // below is the active class that is now being populated accross all items equally
                echo '<li class="nav-item dropdown active">';
                echo '<a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle animated fadeIn animation-delay-7" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-name="services">';
                echo $row["pagename"];
                echo '<i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>';
                echo '</a>';
                // create a new list
                echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                    // loop second/submenu query results
                    while($sub_row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a href="' . $sub_row["link"] . '" class="dropdown-item">' . $sub_row["pagename"] . '</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                echo "</ul>";
                echo '</li>';
            } else { // for all other menu links
                echo '<li class="nav-item dropdown active">';
                echo '<a href="' . $row["link"] . '" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle animated fadeIn animation-delay-7">' . $row["pagename"] . '</a>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

The screenshot below shows the result after it renders. Notice the active class highlighted in yellow, it is added to every item in my main menu (the way I have it coded, which it's wrong of course). The green is the `$sub_row["link"]` (to answer Mark's question below

Notice, the active class is only needed to be added programmatically on the main menu. (the `else` portion of my code).

[image]

The screenshot below shows how the active class affects the menu item if the user was in the `www.domain.com/how-it-works.php` page. The active class contians the styles to make the menu item appear that way.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to test with not having the DB outputs to match against mate but try this, basically you want an if statement to get the current page URL and match it against the url you get back from the DB.

```
<?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $pageURL = str_replace('/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $homeURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        // output data of each row

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($row['id'] == 2){ ?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle animated fadeIn animation-delay-7" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-name="services">
                        <?php echo $row["pagename"];?>
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php while($sub_row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $sub_row["link"]; ?>" class="dropdown-item">
                                    <?php echo $sub_row["pagename"] ?>
                                </a>
                             </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <?php
            } else if($row['id'] == 1){ ?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown <?php echo ($homeURL == $row["link"])? 'active' : '';?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $row["link"]; ?>" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle animated fadeIn animation-delay-7">
                        <?php echo $row["pagename"]; ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php
            } else { ?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown <?php echo ($pageURL == $row["link"])? 'active' : '';?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $row["link"]; ?>" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle animated fadeIn animation-delay-7">
                        <?php echo $row["pagename"]; ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php }
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

Edit:

Bit that gets the current page url is:

```
$pageURL  = end(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Bit that does the check is (this is just a shorthand if statement:

```
<?php echo ($pageURL == $row["link"])? 'active' : '';?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160451/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-adding-an-active-class-according-to-url).